# How to grab data from train sets when bootstrap=False in RF regressor in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

As title

RF regressor decide a tree by grabing part of train data aka bootstrap.

In [sklearn.ensemble.randomforestregressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor):

```
bootstrap : boolean, optional (default=True)
        Whether bootstrap samples are used when building trees.
```

If set bootstrap=False, how would the model grab data?

The reason I'm interesting is when I set it to False, it makes the mse and mae down in my experiments, that's means False is better for me.

Comment: when you say 'False is better for me', is it on the train or test dataset? If it is on the train dataset, then it means the model is over fitting the data

Comment: @AI_Learning both are better for me.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L101) is the relevant code.

Comment: May its not over fitting then, do you see the same different between train and test performance in both models?  Probably increasing the number of trees might help to help you improved your bootstrap model.